postgres.fields.JSONField and models.JSONField
I have a model in some django project it has a JSONField in it.
I want to connect to the table of that model from another django project so i copied the model from first django project and move it to second one.
The first django project uses from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField but i can't use same JSONField in second django project (because of django version in second project it does not support postgres.field.JSONField).
My question is can i use from django.db.models import JSONField in second django project with no errors and connect to the same database?

What is stopping you from trying that?

I tested this approach successfully, confirming that I could create use JSON field and connect it to an existing PostgreSQL database with postgres.JSONField.
